# Meu código ta dando esse erro "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

Tags: javascript, recuperação-de-erros

**HTML PÁGINA 1**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
<body>
    <h1>Formulário</h1>
    <div class="counteiner">
        <div class="item">
            <label for="">Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" class="expandn" id="nome">
            <label for="">Idade:</label>
            <input type="number" class="expandn" id="number">
            <label for="">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="expandn" id="email">
            <label for="">Comentário:</label>
            <input type="text" class="expand" id="coment">
            <button id="buttone">Enviar</button>
            <button id="buttonclear">Limpar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
    var nome = document.getElementById('nome');
var idade = document.getElementById('number');
var email = document.getElementById('coment');
var send = document.getElementById('buttone');
var p1 = document.querySelector('#p1')
var p2 = document.querySelector('#p2')
var p3 = document.querySelector('#p3')
var p4 = document.querySelector('#p4')

send.addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.open('pagina2.html')
    console.log('funcionou');
})
```

**PAGINA HTML2**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
<body>
    <p>Nome:</p><p id="p1"></p>
    <p>Idade:</p><p id="p2"></p>
    <p>Email:</p><p id="p3"></p>
    <p>Comentário</p><p id="p4"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Quero saber como eu passo informações de uma página para a outra sem dar esses erros...

Answer (score -1):

Olá, João Vitor!

O que ocorre é que, quando você chama o arquivo .js em duas páginas ele será executado em ambas as páginas. Portanto, ele executará o js no **HTML PÁGINA 1** tranquilo, porém, quando for executado na **PAGINA HTML2**, ele apontará um erro, pois o javascript procurará um botão com id `buttone` e tentará adicionar um evento nele, só que ele não existe, então ele dá o erro `"Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"`.

Se sua intenção é usar `.addEventListener`, talvez seja mais interessante você criar um arquivo JS para cada página HTML.

Espero ter ajudado.